# low beam lights dont work but high beams do

Tags: chevrolet, lights, traverse

I have A 2012 Chevy Traverse.  My right side light was out so I replaced it, and the new one doesn't work.  ( I tested it on the other side, and it worked fine there) The high beam does work.

I checked the fuse an its fine, however, when my light has burned out in the past, my screen notifies me that its out,  however in this case it hasn't given me any notification.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!